# V-brake / cantilever pad alternatives for carbon rims?

Tags: brakes, brake-pads

I've found these V-brake compatible brake pads rated for carbon rims:

SwissStop RX Plus Yellow King

Trickstuff (unnamed) http://www.trickstuff.de/en/products/felgenbremsbelaege_KL.php

Ice (unnamed)
http://www.dccycles.co.uk/ice-72mm-v-brake-pads-for-carbon-wheels-53558-p.asp

Paul Components (Kool Stop-based)
https://paulcomp.com/shop/service-parts/rim-brake-pads/

They're all some combination of expensive, unattractive, and difficult to find.

Are there any alternatives? Or some way to use standard pads with V-brake shoes (or adapt standard shoes to V-brakes)?

Comment: There are many available for road style caliper brakes. there are not many options for V-brakes as most people that are running carbon rims on an MTB are going to have disc brakes. Kool Stop makes several varieties that are inexpensive but i don't know that they make any for V-Brakes at this time.

Comment: At this point, I'd be content with a conventional pad that just wasn't terrible in the wet.

Comment: I think you're searching for the narrow intersection of two groups that don't really overlap much at all.   Good luck

Comment: If I had the money for carbon rims I'd splurge the extra bit for disc brakes...

Comment: The frame doesn't have disc mounts. You're suggesting to buy another bike.

Comment: Did the bike come with carbon rims and V-Brakes?

Comment: It did not, though apparently there's at least one Giant bike with that combination. It uses the cyclocross brake shoes I referenced in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the best way to go about this is to buy threaded cyclocross brake shoes that take regular road pads. A few:

- Avid Shorty 6 TRP
- TRP Inplace Adjust M
- Jagwire Cross Pro
- Kool Stop Cross Threaded
- Clark's CP453CV
- Tektro 720.12